# moving an image with button android studio

Tags: android, image, object, button, pixel

I have an image in my view and a button. I want to be able to press the button and the image will move down by 1 pixel...

Here is my code for the image and button.

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/line_image"
    android:layout_marginTop="130dp"/>



<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop= "400dp"
    android:text="Closer"/>
```

how should i do this?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could add top margin to the image view every time the button is clicked:

```
Button button = findViewById(R.id.button1);
final ImageView image = findViewById(R.id.image1);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    ((ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams)image.getLayoutParams()).topMargin += 1;
    image.requestLayout();
  }
});
```

Remember to add an id to the `ImageView`.

Comment: where should i add that code? In the MainActivity.java, under the public void oncreate?

Comment: @androooooid underneath `setContentView()`.

Comment: i get some errors when i add that code in... I get errors on the following words: Button, on the first line of code.  ImageView on the second line of code.  SetOnClickListerns the third line of code.  View on the third line as well.  View on the fifth line.  Viewgroup and getlayoutParams on the sixth and requestlayout on the 7th.  They are all red.  Why is that? How can i fix that?

Comment: You need to import the appropriate classes. That's basic java, perhaps you should start with that? Here's a helper: `import android.widget.Button;` it should go before the class declaration. I won't provide any further help as it is out of the scope of your question. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

In your method that gets called by your onClickListener for the button, you can just use something like this:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.your_image_view_id);
float y = imageView.getY();
y++;
imageView.setY(y);
```

Pretty simple.

Answer (score 0):

Add android:onClick="myMethodName" and you can work with Animation and Graphics. [Check this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/overview.html)